# String comparison with strings that contain wildcard operators in C-Shell

Tags: csh

I need to compare a pattern input by the user that may contain wildcards to a given extension. For example if the input is `hy*.gif` I would move the files `hyland.gif` and `hyland2.gif` in a given input directory to an output directory. This is to be done on a case by case basis, where each extension `.gif`, `.tiff`, and `.png` are handled separately.

This is what I tried:

```
if("$pattern" =~ *.gif) then

  #move all .gif files to output directory
```

The body of the if statement is unimportant. I cannot get the expression to return true for the case of `hy*.gif`, however it does return true for the case `*leaves\*.tiff`

Similarly, for checking each file in the input directory I cannot get this expression to return true:

```
if($file =~ *"$pattern")
```

As I understand it, the `=~` operator only expects wildcards on the right-hand side, which might be why it's giving me issues

Is there any other way to use `=~` or a simple command such as grep to perform this check? Or is there a way to make the `*` operator match itself?

Answer (score 2):

It should work. You need to show the values of $pattern by running: echo "$pattern". However you need to space out the if-statement components.

```
if ( "$pattern" =~ *.gif ) then
   echo "pattern matches..."
else
   echo "no match"
endif
```

You could also put the "switch" statement to good use in your scenario:

```
switch ( "$pattern" )
   case "*.gif":
      echo "GIF ok"
      breaksw

   case "*.png":
      echo "PNG ok"
      breaksw

   default:
      echo "No match"
      breaksw
endsw
```